# Morphisms between Prevarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the attached proof from Mumford's Red Book. In particular, I am confused by the statement that "$g•f$ is at least a section of $O_X$ on the sets $f^{-1}(V \cap {V_i})$."I see why $g•f_i$ ($f_i$ as defined in the proof) is a section of $O_X$ on the sets ${f_i}^{-1}(V \cap {V_i})$, but am confused as to how this implies the statement for $f$ itself. Thanks![image: Mumford proof]

Comment: The viewpoint here seems to be that $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a subsheaf of the sheaf $k$-valued functions. In general, if $\mathcal F' \subseteq \mathcal F$ is a subsheaf and $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ then you can check whether $s\in\mathcal{F}'(U)$ on an open cover of $U$.